# How to substring last two tokens from a string separated by dot in ORACLE SQL if only 4 and 5th tokens exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a bunch of strings in a table called code_table and column named code as shown where teach token in the string is separated by a dot. The number of tokens in each string can vary but I have to consider ONLY the strings that have both 4th and 5th tokens and others can be ignored. A code string can have maximum of 5 tokens. If and only if the string contain both 4th and 5th tokens, then I have to concatenate them and create a single code. Here is an example:[Please Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbwdS.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTR` to look for the 4th occurrence of a `.` to determine which rows should be returned, then a simple `SUBSTR` and `REPLACE` to format the result as you would like.

```sql
WITH
    code_table (code)
    AS
        (SELECT 'ppge.34.aaa.fesl' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'aler.56.fghh.sdef.wath' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'apef.23.ared' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'eard.wed' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'wera.fgeg.23d.adef.erff' FROM DUAL)
SELECT REPLACE (SUBSTR (code,
                          INSTR (code,
                                 '.',
                                 1,
                                 3)
                        + 1),
                '.')
  FROM code_table
 WHERE INSTR (code,
              '.',
              1,
              4) > 0;
```

Comment: That is incorrect. A value that has 5 tokens will only have 4 periods so you will need to look for the 4th occurrence of a period.

Comment: You are right, I've mistaken 5th token for the 5th dot. I'll shamefully delete my comment now

Comment: Hahaha no problem! It happens to the best of us.